# At the end of the program (Python), my image does not appear?

Tags: python, image, flickr

My intent is to create a something by something square grid with pictures from flickr. I have written all my code, and it has all worked up to the point where I have tried to adjust the parameters so that I could create a grid of any size (meaning not always strictly 4x4, instead I could put in a 5x5 grid or what have you)

This is a homework assignment, and I have gotten as far as I can. I have no idea why the image isn't popping up after the code has been run through. I've debugged it over and over, and looked at many websites, and I have no idea! I am relatively new to programming, so please understand. Thank you in advance for any advice or clues!

```
import flickr import Image

def adjust_sizing(image):
    (w, h) = image.size

    #proportionality
    height = ((256*h)/w)
    width = ((w/h) * 256)

    if h > w:
        image = image.resize(( 256 , (height) ))
    elif w > h:
        image = image.resize(( (width) , 256 ))

    image = image.crop(( 0, 0, 256, 256))
    image.save("image.png")
    return image


def photocollage(tag, number, rawnum, canvas):
    url_list = flickr.getphotos(apicode, tag, number)

    #number is number of images needed total
    #rawnumb is number of rows/columns

    #Create list of all coordinates that need to be occupied
    coordinates = set()
    i = 0
    while i < rawnum:
        w = (256 * i)
        j = 0
        while j < rawnum:
            h = (256 * j)
            j += 1
            coordinates.add((w,h))
    i += 1
    coordinates.add((w,h))
    cords = list(coordinates)

    #Create list for all images that need to be matched with a coordinate
    imagelist = []
    for url in url_list:
        image = flickr.openphoto(url)
        image.save("image.png")
        image = adjust_sizing(image)
        imagelist.append(image)

    #paste to canvas image in image list[k] at coordinates cords[k]
    k = 0
    while k <= number:
        canvas.paste(imagelist[k], cords[k])  


    #return final image
    return canvas


 def create_wallpaper(tag, length, output_name):
          collage = Image.new('RGB', (length, length), 'white')
          image = photocollage(tag, (length**2), length, collage)
          image.save(output_name)
          image.show()        


 apicode = '219084039852' #I made this up for now, it's irrelevant

 create_wallpaper("cats", 4, "catpic.png")
```

I know it's a pretty long block of code, but I am really frustrated. I know for sure the function adjust sizing works.

It might be because I've been staring at this code for 8 hours, but I hope you can help my figure out my error. I need to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You are never incrementing `k` so your `while` loop never finishes.

You might as well just use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
for k in range(0, number):
    canvas.paste(imagelist[k], cords[k])
```

Comment: but image.show() worked previously.. why would it be that now it doesn't work?